# Changing period of dates to standard date to do line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot a line graph with R using the dataset that can be found [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/conditionsanddiseases/bulletins/coronaviruscovid19caseratesbysociodemographiccharacteristicsengland/1september2020to10december2021) . I'm looking specifically at how to plot the number of cases in each region i.e. north east, north west etc against the period of time.

However, as the date is a period of a week rather than a standard date, how can I convert it to make the line graph actually possible? For example, right now it has the dates as 01/09/2020 - 07/09/2020. How can I use this for a line graph?

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear, here is a picture below.

[image]

Comment: You can use `as.factor(Period)` ("Period" = whatever column name you give to plot on the x-axis) in the `aes()` to use character data in an x-axis. Right now you also have issues with column names, obviously, but this answers your specific question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to plot a time series? You could just trim the dates to the beginning of the week and label the time axis as "Week beginning on date". You could do this with [substr()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substr) in base r and keep the first 10 characters.

```
substr(data$column,1,10)
```

You may also want to format it as a date, easiest with the [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org), something like [dmy()](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html) (day month year).

Here is the full code you would want:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Read in data
data <- read.csv("/Users/sabrinaxie/Downloads/covid19casesbysociodemographiccharacteristicengland1sep2020to10dec20213.csv")

#Modify data and remove extraneous top rows
data <- data %>% 
  rename(Period=Table.9..Weekly.estimates.of.age.standardised.COVID.19.case.rates..per.100.000.person.weeks..by.region..England..1.September.2020.to.6.December.20211.2.3) %>% 
  slice(3:n())

#Keep first 10 characters of Period column and assign to old column to replace
data$Period <- substr(data$Period,1,10)

#Parse as date
data$Period <- dmy(data$Period)
```

Comment: When using the dmy() it gives me NA values as can be seen below: 
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[39] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

Not sure what I've done wrong?

Comment: Could you post a code snippet? It works for me with the code: `dmy("29/09/2020")` parsing as "2020-09-29" You should be doing this after the substring step

Comment: so I did `substr(covidData$`Table 9: Weekly estimates of age-standardised COVID-19 case rates (per 100,000 person-weeks) by region, England: 1 September 2020 to 6 December 20211,2,3`)` and then I did `dmy(covidData$`Table 9: Weekly estimates of age-standardised COVID-19 case rates (per 100,000 person-weeks) by region, England: 1 September 2020 to 6 December 20211,2,3`)`

sorry the title of the row is extremely long - I will be changing the name soon

Comment: I suggest you change the name of that column to something shorter and without spaces for simplicity since it's a little hard to read that. Did you substring to the first 10 characters? I can't see the second and third arguments in your substr() function

Comment: I have just renamed it: 
first I did `substr(covidData$weekBeginning,1,10)` and then I did `dmy(covidData$weekBeginning)` which resulted in `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[39] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`

Comment: You didn't assign the new column to anything so you haven't changed the original dataset. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: In rstudio it says that the column name has been changed to `weekBeginning` so I'm a little confused. It won't let me add a screenshot to show you unfortunately

Comment: You changed the column name correctly but when you do a function like substring in R, you need to assign those new values to the old column to replace those values. Otherwise, the new values are not saved anywhere and you have not changed anything. Think of it like doing the math in your head and not writing it down. Basically R did the calculations but you didn't ask it to write it down anywhere.

Comment: Ah I see. I just managed to duplicate the data then actually do it properly (which seems to have worked). Annoyingly though when I do`dmy(covidData2$weekBeginning` a warning message pops up saying`Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `weekBeginning`. is this to do with the same thing?

Comment: If the rest of it is working I wouldn't worry about it. That usually means that the column you are referring to doesn't exist. You could double check the dataframe has a column of that name using `names(covidData2)`, the output should include "weekBeginning".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242769/discussion-between-sabrina-xie-and-sarah).